# Python Django views.py filter button doesn't work

Tags: python, django

My models.py:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipe_title = models.CharField("Назва Рецепту", max_length=50)
    recipe_text = models.TextField("Текст Рецепту")
    recipe_image = models.ImageField(default="", null=True, blank=True, upload_to="recipeImages/")
    isHot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isVegan = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author_name = models.CharField("Імʼя автора", max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Дата публікації")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe_title

    def isHOT(self):
        if self.isHot == True:
            return self.recipe_title
```

My views.py:

```
def index(request):
    latest_recipes = Recipe.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    search_query = request.GET.get('search', '')

    if 'ishot' in request.POST:
        recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(isHot=True).all()
    else:
        recipes = Recipe.objects.all()

    if search_query:
        recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(recipe_title__icontains=search_query)
    else:
        recipes = Recipe.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'recipes/list.html', {'latest_recipes': latest_recipes, 'recipes': recipes})
```

My html page:

```
    {% for a in recipes %}  
    
        <a href="{% url 'recipes:detail' a.id %}" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="{{a.recipe_image.url}}" style="width: 15%; float:left">
                    <div id="text">
                        <h3>{{a.recipe_title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{a.recipe_text}}</p>
                    {% if a.was_published_recently %}
                        <h4 style="color: red;">NEW</h4>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if a.isHOT %}
                        <img style="width:3%;" src="/images/hot.png" name="#">
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if a.isVEGAN %}
                        <img style="width:3%;" src="/images/vegan.png" name="#">
                    {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </a>       
    {% endfor %}
```

'search_query' function works, 'ishot' function itself works as well, but filter 'recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(isHot=True).all()' doesn't. It should filter objects, similar function do it's job, I have no clue what is problem in

My db(there are ukrainian words):
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you need to call `.all()` after the filter part? Maybe thats the issue

Comment: also explain whats wrong, just 'doesn't work' isn't really a valid explanation of the problem, share desired output and what you're getting

Comment: I had tried but it didn't work

Comment: It shoulder filter objects, similar function do it's job, I have no clue what is problem in

Answer (score 1):

You are making GET request to the view, but you are looking for `ishot` in `request.POST`. Hence you should fix it by:

```
if request.GET.get('ishot', False):
    recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(isHot=True).all()
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help, request works, filter doesn't

Comment: Can you check your database to see if there is any Recipe with isHot true?

Comment: I added image of db to question

Comment: By the way, what do you get when you print Recipe.objects.filter(isHot=True).all()?